# Are there terms to separate two different notions of percentage increase?

Tags: interest-rate, stock-market, definition

Say someone owns 30% of the shares of a company. Then suppose that they increase their number of shares by 50%.  This last sentence is ambiguous. It could mean that they increase their number of shares to a total of 45%, or to a total of 80%. It depends whether we 50% is relative to their current shares or to the total possible shares.

Are there words or terms to delineate between the two concepts?  This would apply whenever the unit of measurement is a rate, proportion, etc.  For example, inflation, interest rates, etc.

Comment: this seems to be english language question, not economics question

Comment: How do economists specify which meaning they are intending?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are **percent (%)** and there are **percentage points (%p)**.

- In your example, an increase from 30% to 45% is an increase of 50% and at the same time an increase of 15%p.
- An increase in interest rate from 1% to 2% is a 100% increase and a 1%p increase at the same time.

See also [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262314/is-50-100-higher-than-25-or-is-it-25-higher-than-25/262316#262316).

Comment: Thank you. Would 1 basis point increase therefore be a .01%p increase ?

Comment: @Eoin, yes, it would be.